# Selecting multiple checkboxes in list view in Appium

Tags: appium

I have list of items that has a check option, I need to select all the items.
The attributes available are resource-id, index which are static.
Instance which is dynamic and increases with the list of items eg: 0,1,2...

How can I select all the checkboxes in the list.

```
WebElement checkboxSelection = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.xxxxx[contains (@instance, '0')]");
        checkboxSelection.click();

WebElement checkboxSelection = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.xxxxx[contains (@instance, '1')]");
        checkboxSelection.click();

WebElement checkboxSelection = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.xxxxx[contains (@instance, '2')]");
        checkboxSelection.click();
```

The above code does just a single selection, since I want to select also 1,2,...n how could I achieve this?

I tried something like this and this doesn't result in locating the element

```
for (int j=0;j<=10;j++){
            WebElement contactSelection = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.CheckBox"+j+"instance");
            contactSelection.click();
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't Appium support findElement**s**ByXpath method?

Comment: What do you mean ? I'm using Xpath, please have a look at the code

Comment: What are the possible values for `instance` attribute?

Comment: 0,1,2 ..... like already mentioned in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.xxxxx"));
for(WebElement element: elements){
    element.click();
}
```

first line will return you all the available elements which you then click one-by-one.

Comment: R Perfect, this works for the first view, what if I have to scroll and select the next items ? Thanks

Comment: Then you perform the same code (after scrolling).

Comment: I'm facing issues when I try to do scroll with Touchactions

Comment: I think it is worth raising a separate question for that.

Comment: @WiredTheories oh, I can see that you have already raised it :) Sorry!